# Consequence of Lifting property of Bruhat ordering

Tags: coxeter-groups, weyl-group, bruhat-order

I am reading the book: **Anders Björner, Francesco Brenti --- Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups**.

[image]

I would like to know whether a variation of Corollary 2.2.8 is true. In other words, does the following holds:

> For $s\in S$, $t\in T$, $s\neq t$, $w<sw<stw\implies tw<stw$.

Where $<$ is the Bruhat ordering. Note that $sw<stw\implies w<tw$.

The assertion is true under the assumption $\ell(tw)=\ell(w)+1$ by the proof of Corollary 2.2.8.

A proof of Corollary 2.2.8 can be found on **James E. Humphreys---Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups** (Lemma 5.11).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not true. Take $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ with simple reflections $r, s$. Then the longest element $t := rsr=srs$ is also a reflection. Put $w=e$.

Then $w=e < sw=s < stw = rs$, but $tw = srs \nless stw = rs$.